# error while inserting in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am getting this error while inserting in my table:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`giftme`.`giftme_shop`, CONSTRAINT `shop_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sh_cid`) REFERENCES `giftme_shop_category` (`sc_cid`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO `giftme_shop` (`sh_uid`, `sh_shop_name`, `sh_cid`) VALUES ('79', 'Naveen Reddys shop', 1)

Filename: /var/www/apps/helpers/sessions_helper.php

Line Number: 55
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is foreign key reference

```
parent : `giftme_shop_category`.`sc_cid`
child : `giftme_shop`.sh_cid
```

there is no value of `sc_cid=1` in parent table

Remove Foreign Key constraint

`ALTER TABLE giftme_shop DROP FOREIGN KEY shop_ibfk_2;`

read here

#### http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol
```

Comment: I didnt get you..how to rectify it then?